# Azure Ubuntu VM Cannot Bind IP (public)?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, azure, ip-address

I just started trying out an Ubuntu 16.04 VM on Azure. A node.js app requires listening to a port 3000 on the network interface assigned with the public IP address so remote clients can connect to it over the internet.

However, the node.js app is throwing the error

```
 Error: bind EADDRNOTAVAIL 13.75.111.31:3000
```

I have already added an `inbound security rule` to the network security group to allow:

- Source: Any
- Protocol: Any
- Source port range: *
- Destination: Any
- Destination port range: 3000
- Action: Allow

and this network security group is assigned to the VM.

Additionally, `ifconfig` returns only the private ip address `10.0.0.4` on the interface `eth0` and the `lo` local loopback. There is no interface found for the public ip address `13.75.111.31`.

How can we fixed this problem? Is something setup wrongly?

Comment: You should configure your systems listen on `10.0.0.4`, the private IP.

Answer (score 1):

The public IP is not available to you directly on your VM. Rather, Azure performs 1:1 NAT between that IP and your machine's private IP. So, just configure your systems to listen on the private IP. Assuming network-level things are configured correctly, it should just work.